# WebPart cleanly render a list of n items

Tags: kentico

I am attempting to create a WebPart in Kentico 11 that supports handling an n-length list of items. I found that creating a WebPart with property fields is pretty straightforward in Kentico, but I am having trouble finding documentation on how to best set up a WebPart that can lookup & output *multiple* model objects.

I've tried the following approach, but it has some drawbacks that I'm not entirely comfortable with:

1. Set up a Container page type to place instances of data objects inside. I restricted it to ensure that only my custom Page Type data object is available as a child of it.
2. Place a Pages DataSource in the template zone and direct it to the Container page.
3. Hook up a Repeater element to it and apply a transformation & content before+after to the Repeater.

While this works, it feels a little cludgey. Content editors have to be wise enough to know how to set up DataSources & Repeaters, plus how to bind them together and apply transforms, and additionally remember to fill in the `content before` and `content after` fields with the appropriate wrapping HTML markup.

This is not something that I expect a content editor should need to remember.

Is there a cleaner way to put lists of items inside of a template zone without needing to drag & configure a datasource and container page?

I did not see any way to set up a Page Type field in such a way that it would essentially model a one-to-many relationship with another Page Type.  Did I miss something there?  If I could do that, then I could write a transformation to handle the wrapping HTML markup, and the looping of children.  Haven't been able to find a way to make this work though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to accomplish what you are asking is with a custom form control. In your case, the form control should be able to let users select multiple items.

You can actually use '[Sortable multiple object selector](https://devnet.kentico.com/marketplace/inline-controls/sortable-multiple-object-selector)' marketplace item for this purpose. This form control will enable you to select multiple items based on a certain type (that you need to configure in code) and editors would simply use the select dialog to choose the items.

Comment: Can you point the Multiple Object Selector to arbitrary Page Types?  It looks like it can only look up by the built-in system object types (cms.document, cms.user, etc).  I would need the ability to show the users only my custom model type.

That said, I do see how I could build a custom Form Control to build what I am trying to achieve.  I was really hoping this would be something that Kentico provided out-of-the-box, as it seems like it would make both development & content entry a whole lot easier.

Comment: I believe you can because the code seems to be asking for a 'DataSet' and should not care what data is inside. In the code you also configure what 'Field' is displayed to editors so you shouldn't need to worry about it. If for some reason this doesn't work exactly as you need, you are free to adjust the code as you see fit - there are no restrictions and you see full source code of it.